# How to make transparent background of a Flex button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, transparent

I want to make a Flex button that has it's background transparent in order to apply css to the page and affecting the flash.

I tried, but with no luck:

```
<mx:Button skin="{null}" x="0" y="0" label="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Flex 3 only or can you use Flex 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is using `mx:LinkButton`, unfortunately `LinkButtonSkin` hardcoded alpha=1 for all states but you can override it:

```
package
{
import flash.geom.Matrix;

import mx.skins.halo.LinkButtonSkin;

public class LinkButtonAlphaSkin extends LinkButtonSkin
{
    public function LinkButtonAlphaSkin()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function drawRoundRect(x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number, cornerRadius:Object=null, color:Object=null, alpha:Object=null, gradientMatrix:Matrix=null, gradientType:String="linear", gradientRatios:Array=null, hole:Object=null):void
    {
        super.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, cornerRadius, color, 0, gradientMatrix, gradientType, gradientRatios, hole);
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
<mx:LinkButton label="lala" skin="LinkButtonAlphaSkin"/>
```

Comment: [compiled](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/transp_btn_test/flex3test.swf) version of my code (sdk 3.6) and sources: [flex3test.mxml](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/transp_btn_test/flex3test.mxml), [LinkButtonAlphaSkin.as](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/transp_btn_test/LinkButtonAlphaSkin.as)

Comment: ok, if you need to set the hole swf transparent the obly way to do this is wmode="transparent" while embedding swf object in the html page

Comment: I updated the demo, [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/transp_btn_test/index.xhtml) is the html example of transparent button

Answer (score 3):

When using a Spark Button, you can apply a custom skin that leaves out all the chrome.
You can apply a custom skin like this:

```
<s:Button label="Submit" skinClass="TransparentButtonSkin"/>
```

@Panciz' solution will probably work, but the skin can be made much more lightweight by simply leaving out all the components that you don't need.

```
<!--TransparentButtonSkin.mxml-->
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/>
        <s:State name="over"/>
        <s:State name="down"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect id="hitZone" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
             textAlign="center" maxDisplayedLines="1" verticalAlign="middle"/>

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

Notice the `hitzone` transparent graphic: that is necessary because otherwise you would click through the transparent section of the Button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a new Skinclass and define the alpha property for all the component, I tried with the spark button and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

    ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
    Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    All Rights Reserved.

    NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
    in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for the Spark Button component.  

       @see spark.components.Button

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
             minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
             alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[         
            import spark.components.Group;
            /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
            For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
            static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

            /** 
             * @private
             */     
            override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function initializationComplete():void
            {
                useChromeColor = true;
                super.initializationComplete();
            }  

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");

                if (cornerRadius != cr)
                {
                    cornerRadius = cr;
                    shadow.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    fill.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    lowlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    highlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    border.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                }

                if (highlightStroke) highlightStroke.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke1) hldownstroke1.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke2) hldownstroke2.radiusX = cornerRadius;

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }

            private var cornerRadius:Number = 2;

        ]]>        
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- layer 1: shadow -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="shadow"  left="-1" right="-1" top="-1" bottom="-1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF"
                                 alpha="0.01"
                                 alpha.down="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 alpha="0.07"
                                 alpha.down="0.5" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 2: fill -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="fill" alpha="{0.1}" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 color.over="0xBBBDBD" 
                                 color.down="0xAAAAAA" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                                 color.over="0x9FA0A1" 
                                 color.down="0x929496" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 3: fill lowlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="lowlight" alpha="{0.1}" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="270">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.0" alpha="0.0627" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48" alpha="0.0099" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48001" alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 4: fill highlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlight" alpha="{0.1}" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.0"
                                 alpha="0.33" 
                                 alpha.over="0.22" 
                                 alpha.down="0.12"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48"
                                 alpha="0.33"
                                 alpha.over="0.22"
                                 alpha.down="0.12" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48001"
                                 alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 5: highlight stroke (all states except down) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlightStroke" alpha="{0.1}" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" excludeFrom="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha.over="0.22" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" alpha.over="0.22" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 6: highlight stroke (down state only) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke1" alpha="{0.1}"  left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.001" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.0011" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.965" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.9651" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke2" alpha="{0.1}" left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.09" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.0001" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 7: border - put on top of the fill so it doesn't disappear when scale is less than 1 -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="border" alpha="{0.1}" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="69" height="20" radiusX="2">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.5625"
                                 alpha.down="0.6375" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.75" 
                                 alpha.down="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 8: text -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay  -->
    <s:Label  id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="center"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1" verticalAlign="middle"
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```